# COUNTIF with multiple OR-criterias in different columns

Tags: excel

I have the following Excel spreadsheet:

```
       A          B               C         D        E        F         G
1               Profit           1.Sales  2.Sale   3.sale     
2   Product A     50              500       600       0      Product A   2
3   Product A     60                0       400       0      Product B   1  
4   Prodcut A     20                0         0       0      Product C   2
5   Product B     90              800         0       500
6   Product C     80                0         0       400
7   Product C     50              300       750       200
8   =""           =""             =""        =""       =""
```

In **Column A** different products are listed. *It can happen that the same products appear several times in the list.* In **Column B** you can find the budgeted profit for each product and in **Columns C:E** the different sales of each product.

In **Column G** the **number** of profits for each product is shown in case the product has any sales. For example **Product A** has no sale in Row 4; therefore the **number** of its profit is B2 and B3 = 2.

To get right number in **Column G** I tried to go with the following formula:

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$7,F2,$C$2:$C$7,">"&0,$D$2:$D$7,">"&0,$E$2:$E$7,">"&0)
```

But instead of the AND-criterias I would need OR-criterias.

How can use OR-critierans in this COUNTIFS function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use SUM(COUNTIF(criteria1,range),COUNTIF(criteria2,range),etc).

Each count if looks at only one criteria. If its not met nothing is added, but it does not short circuit the other criteria.

Answer (score 0):

You can't really do these using COUNTIFS, one way is to use a SUMPRODUCT like this

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A$2:A$10=F2)*SIGN(C$2:C$10+D$2:D$10+E$2:E$10))
```

Assuming the profits are positive, SIGN will give a 1 if any of them are non-zero in a particular row. The first bracket in the SUMPRODUCT checks that the row contains the matching product: if TRUE it is multiplied by the second bracket to give a 1 if both conditions are met. Then the SUMPRODUCT adds all the 1's.

[image]